# MacOS – AppleScript or JSA -- accessing getting current application causing error

Tags: applescript, ui-automation, automator

I've got a really simple script, in this case written as JS using Javascript For Automation, instead of Applescript (I'd be fine getting a solution in Applescript if someone can help).  The script simply deletes the currently-playing file in VLC.app. I have the script assigned to a keyboard shortcut.

I have more than one instance of VLC running though, each launched via the terminal command:

```sh
open -n /Applications/VLC.app
```

This following script *mostly* does what I want, but, it **always** interacts with whichever instance of VLC.app I opened first — not the focused, *active instance*.

```js
let vlc = Application("VLC");
vlc.includeStandardAdditions = true

let file = vlc.pathOfCurrentItem.get()
let path = Path(file);

var dialogText = "Delete file " + file + "?"
let result = vlc.displayDialog(dialogText, {
  buttons: ["No", "Yes"],
  defaultButton: "Yes",
   cancelButton: "No"
})


if (result.buttonReturned == "Yes") {
  let finder = Application("Finder");
  finder.delete(path)      
}
```

**I'm trying to get the *focused* app instance**, so I changed the first line to:

```js
let vlc = Application.currentApplication();
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:

[image: error message]

I've spent way too much time on this, so I figured I'd see if someone can tell me what I'm missing!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem are the multiple running VLC instances. How does AppleScript know which instance is the proper target?

Answer (score 2):

Don’t generally recommend JXA over AppleScript as JXA breaks a lot of stuff that works in AS. However, this is one use-case where JXA does have the advantage, as it can target by Process ID instead of application name, e.g. `Application(123)`. Obtaining PIDs for existing processes (e.g. via `NSWorkspace.runningApplications`) is left as an exercise.

p.s. `current application` is the process that’s running the script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer –– I'm not following where I would interact with NSWorkspace.runningApplications (i.e. that sounds like Swift/Foundation code) through Applescript/JXA...